# How to fix table's caption that is overlapping the content.

Tags: tables, captions

I have an table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Test wydajnosci wykonanej aplikacji mierzony w czasie odpowiedzi serwera 000webhost.com w milisekundach na wybrane zapytania.}
 \begin{tabular}{| p{6cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{2.4cm} | } 
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{ {\bf Czasy odpowiedzi:} } \\ \hline
 {\bf  Typy zapytań}  &  {\bf  Srednia \mbox{arytmetyczna}} & {\bf Mediana} & {\bf Odchylenie standardowe} \\ \hline

 Próba przeniesienia karty & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
 Żądania generowane podczas standardowej rozgrywki & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
 Zapytania niedozwolone (wbrew regułom) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
 Zapytania niedozwolone (niepoprawny format) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
 Odsyłanie literału & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
 Przeglądanie strony www opartej o WordPress & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline

 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Which render to this:
[image]

The table's caption is obviously bad positioned, overlapping the table's content.

**How can I fix that and make the caption appear above the table?**

Comment: Please add some more info since as it is, it's not reproducible

Comment: No problem here with you single code. By the way, replace `center` environment by `\centering`.

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ document so that people can reproduce the problem and test answers (and load the correct language hyphenation patters etc)

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an MWE which shows your actual state. Your provided code does not result in an error. However, I fixed it a bit for you. Here is how I would type it (including a `booktabs`-version in the end:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Test wydajnosci wykonanej aplikacji mierzony w czasie odpowiedzi serwera \url{000webhost.com} w milisekundach na wybrane zapytania.}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\RaggedRight}p{4.25cm} |  *{3}{S[table-format=1.1]|} } 
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{ \textbf{Czasy odpowiedzi}: } \\ \hline
        \textbf{Typy zapytań}  &  {\specialcell{\textbf{Srednia}\\\textbf{arytmetyczna}}} & \textbf{Mediana} & {\specialcell{\textbf{Odchylenie}\\\textbf{standardowe}}} \\ \hline          
        Próba przeniesienia karty & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
        Żądania generowane podczas standardowej rozgrywki & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
        Zapytania niedozwolone (wbrew regułom) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
        Zapytania niedozwolone (niepoprawny format) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
        Odsyłanie literału & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
        Przeglądanie strony www opartej o WordPress & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline         
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\setcounter{section}{4}\setcounter{subsection}{4}\setcounter{subsubsection}{1}
\subsubsection{Testy regresyjne}
%
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Booktabs-version}
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\RaggedRight}p{4.3cm} *{3}{S[table-format=1.1]} } 
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{ c }{ \textbf{Czasy odpowiedzi}: } \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
        \textbf{Typy zapytań}  &  {\specialcell{\textbf{Srednia}\\\textbf{arytmetyczna}}} & \textbf{Mediana} & {\specialcell{\textbf{Odchylenie}\\\textbf{standardowe}}} \\ \midrule            
        Próba przeniesienia karty & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\\cmidrule{1-4}
        Żądania generowane podczas standardowej rozgrywki & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\\cmidrule{1-4}
        Zapytania niedozwolone (wbrew regułom) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\\cmidrule{1-4}
        Zapytania niedozwolone (niepoprawny format) & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\\cmidrule{1-4}
        Odsyłanie literału & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\\cmidrule{1-4}
        Przeglądanie strony www opartej o WordPress & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ \bottomrule            
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]